# Object won't copy properly

Tags: javascript, redux

While trying to cover my React/Redux application with tests I've issued the following problem: my reducer changes initial state object, despite the fact that I copy that object inside reducer.

Here is reducer code:

```
[actionTypes.POINT_REMOVE]: (state, action) => {
    const newState = { ...state }
    const { byId, ids } = newState;
    const { id } = action;

    ids.splice(ids.indexOf(id), 1);
    delete byId[id];

    return {
      ...newState,
      byId: {
        ...byId
      },
      ids: [...ids],
    };
  },
```

And here is the tests code:

```
describe('with non-empty state', () => {
    const firstId = 123;
    const secondId = 456;
    const thirdId = 789;

    const initialState = {
      byId: {
        [firstId]: {
          id: firstId,
        },
        [secondId]: {
          id: secondId,
        },
        [thirdId]: {
          id: thirdId,
        },
      },
      ids: [firstId, secondId, thirdId],
    };

    describe('on POINT_REMOVE action', () => {
      it('should remove point', () => {  
        const expectedState = {
          byId: {
            [secondId]: {
              id: secondId,
            },
            [thirdId]: {
              id: thirdId,
            },
          },
          ids: [secondId, thirdId],
        };

        const action = actionCreators.removePoint(firstId);
        const actualState = pointsReducer(initialState, action);

        expect(actualState).toEqual(expectedState);
      });
    });

    describe('on POINT_OREDER_CHANGE action', () => {
      it('should change order of elements in ids array', () => {
        const oldIndex = 1;
        const newIndex = 2;

        console.log(initialState);

        const expectedState = {
          byId: {
            [firstId]: {
              id: firstId,
            },
            [secondId]: {
              id: secondId,
            },
            [thirdId]: {
              id: thirdId,
            }
          },
          ids: [firstId, thirdId, secondId],
        };

        const action = actionCreators.changePointOrder({ oldIndex, newIndex });
        const actualState = pointsReducer(initialState, action);

        expect(actualState).toEqual(expectedState);
      });
    });
```

While I log `initialState` value to console in `on POINT_ORDER_CHANGE action` block, it gives me `initialState` value without the first element, as if it was modified inside `POINT_REMOVE` reducer.

What do I do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I've fixed it changing `initialState` object declaration to a factory function, but I'm wondering, why object copying with spread operator won't work, or if I understand it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is likely to do with this line:

```
    const newState = { ...state }
```

newState will indeed be a copy of `state`, however it won't be a deep copy. This means that objects nested within your `state` object will be copied by reference rather than the values being re-created as a new object. That is, you are modifying the original `byId` and `id` objects. In the way it is here, the original objects will be updated. If you don't want that to happen, you will need to deeply clone your state object, or, make copies of `byId` and `id` and applying your mutations to those rather than the original objects.

eg:
making copies of `byId` and `id` (personally preferred method)

```
  const newState = { ...state }
    const { byId, ids } = newState;
    const { id } = action;
    const copyById = { ...byId };
    const copyIds = [...ids];
```

or a deep clone of `state`:

```
const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Seems like that is a common mistake, my bad. :)

Comment: it's an easy mistake to make! I still do it on occasion